# Word Organizer does not copy style indentation or hanging indent correctly

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, indentation, bullets

When I use the import/export organizer to copy certain Word styles, it changes the indent and hanging indent when copying. For instance:

Indent: Left: 0", 
Hanging: 1.25"

changes to

Indent: Left: 0.25", 
Hanging: 0.25"

This is a Paragraph style type, based on: (no style). It happens only on Bulleted styles.

This problem happens whether copying from or to Normal.dotm or to another blank or existing document. We are using Word365 and Word2016. It happens to all three of us in the department (we share styles).

Is there some way to override this "feature" during import/export? Currently we have to manually edit every bullet style in every document to reset it to zero indent.

I have tried copying it 3 times in a row, as someone suggested.
I have the correct styles in Normal.dotm and new blank documents have the correct indents. They just can't be copied to existing documents.

Comment: It sounds like some of the formatting is applied via the bulleted list rather than the paragraph style.  Probably the easiest way to get around this is to copy/paste the bulleted list into your new document, using Paste | Keep Source Formatting (K).

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get this to work only by deleting ALL bullet styles from the "to" document and choosing Use Destination Theme when copying the styled text (5 styles). This correctly copied the styles. Otherwise, it would not overwrite existing styles even though I chose Keep Source Formatting.